# Python Module to format text files

Tags: python, module, format

I have a series of firewall configs that has some really bad formating (fortinet), and we are trying to put all the firewall rules into a excel spreadsheet with columns and rows with corresponding information. I remember we could use a python module to do that, but I forgot the name of that when importing....Any experts can provide some pointers?

The firewall config file looks like this:

```
config firewall policy 1
    edit eth1
    set srcintf 33
    set srcaddr 10.50.43.28 255.255.255.255
    set dstintf 31
    set dstaddr all
    set schedule always
    set service https
    set action accept
end

config firewall policy 2
    edit eth1
    set srcintf 33
    set srcaddr 10.50.45.28 255.255.255.255
    set dstintf 31
    set dstaddr all
    set schedule always
    set service https, ftp
    set action accept
end
```

and the end result would be a table (csv file)

```
Policy Name Source Address  Destination Address Service Action

1       10.50.43.28 255.255.255.255 all https   accept


2       10.50.45.28 255.255.255.255 all https, ftp  accept
```

THanks a lot

Comment: Possible to write a simple custom parser for config files like that, but in the meantime maybe checkout this tool [Fortinet Config Parse Tool v0.3](https://github.com/Fatal-Halt/FortiGate-Config-Parser)

Answer (score 1):

You should check:

- Python's [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to learn how to read and write files
- Python's string[.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples) to learn how to format the log the way you want

Here follows what I came up with using python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open('log.txt', 'r') as log:
    csv = 'Policy,Name Source Address,Destination Address,Service,Action\n'
    policy_text = 'config firewall policy'
    name_text = 'set srcaddr'
    destination_text = 'set dstaddr'
    service_text = 'set service'
    action_text = 'set action'

    def value(text, text_type):
        return text.replace(text_type, '').strip()

    for line in log.readlines():
        if policy_text in line:
            policy = value(line, policy_text)
        elif name_text in line:
            name = value(line, name_text)
        elif destination_text in line:
            destination = value(line, destination_text)
        elif service_text in line:
            service = value(line, service_text)
        elif action_text in line:
            action = value(line, action_text)
        elif 'end' in line:
            csv = '{}"{}","{}","{}","{}","{}"\n'.format(
            csv, policy, name, destination, service, action)

    with open('log.csv', 'w') as final_log:
        print(csv, file=final_log)
```